# Android Kotlin Retrofit Post Request Inputted data does not sent

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

So I have to handle a POST request with its body data taken from some input in a form.
The Endpoint of this service is `https://someUrl.com/someURL/param?paramA=123`
The Response returned from Postman is like [this][1].

The body of this request is like this :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

In this case, I have this Interface for handling a POST request:

```
///Endpoint: https://someUrl.com/someURL/param?paramA=123

 interface editProductDetail{
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("switch")
    fun editProductDetail(@Query("orderID") orderID: String,
                      @Query("procode") procode: String,
                      @Query("nip") nip : String,

                      @Field("procode_new") procodeNew: String,
                      @Field("item_qty_new") itemQtyNew: String,
                      @Field("item_price_new") itemPriceNew: String,
                      @Field("item_name_new") itemNameNew: String,
                      @Field("total_price_new") totalPriceNew: String): Call<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassDetailItem>
}
```

This is the data class I use:

```
 data class OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassDetailItem(

    @field:SerializedName("item_price_new")
    val itemPriceNew: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("item_name_new")
    val itemNameNew: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("total_price")
    val totalPrice: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("item_price")
    val itemPrice: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("item_name")
    val itemName: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status_refund")
    val statusRefund: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("detail_id")
    val detailId: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("procode_new")
    val procodeNew: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("refund_date")
    val refundDate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("request_refund")
    val requestRefund: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("procode")
    val procode: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("last_update")
    val lastUpdate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("item_qty_new")
    val itemQtyNew: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("order_id")
    val orderId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("total_price_new")
    val totalPriceNew: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("item_qty")
    val itemQty: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("refund")
    val refund: Int? = null
)
```

As you can see above, the body has attributes that are included in the data class as well. (This data class is also used in a related service in the App that uses the inputted data of this service).

And this is the function to trigger the POST request:

```
NetworkConfig().editOutstandingOrderProductDetailService().editProductDetail(
        selectedOrderId,
        selectedProcode,
        selectedNip,
        procodeNew,
        itemNewQty,
        itemPriceNew,
        itemNewName,
        totalPriceNew

    ).enqueue(object :
        Callback<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassDetailItem> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassDetailItem>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.i("Order", "It Failed!!")

            if (call.isCanceled) {
                Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), "Request Aborted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            } else {
                Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), t.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassDetailItem>,
            response: Response<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassDetailItem>
        ) {
            Log.i("Order", "Switching Process done!!!")
            Log.i("Order", "Status: ${response.body()}")
        }
    })
```

From above, it prints the response in the logCat like this:

[image]

Am I missing something here? Or there's something I need to Change? If there's any detail that I missed to point out, just let me know!

Comment: request is JSON body request not formurl encoded

Comment: @silentsudo So... How should I modify the code so it can handle a body request ? I should edit Both in Interface and The function to trigger the POST request, right ?. Sorry I'm really new when it comes to handling POST request.

Comment: is response 200?

Comment: @Sairaj Sawant in postman ? Yes it is.

Comment: no not in postman. try `log.d("tag", response )` in `onResponse`

Comment: @SairajSawant Yes it is 200

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your request is a `JSON object`, not a `formurl`.
`@Field` tag is used when you want to pass your parameters as `formurl`

Use **model class** or **JsonObject** with @Body tag to pass parameters as `JsonObject`.

Model class Exmaple,

```
data class TestClass{  
    val text1: String,
    val text2: String 
}
```

Now Pass this class as request

```
@POST("URL")
fun apiName(@Body request: TestClass);
```

JSON Object Exmaple,

```
JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
 paramObject.put("key1", "value1");
 paramObject.put("key1", "vaalue2");
```

Now pass it as `String` or `JsonObject`

```
@POST("URL")
fun apiName(@Body request: String); // pass as String
```

Comment: I see. I finally understood. Thanks dude!